# Primefaces DynaForm always return null values

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

When using [primefaces dynaform](http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/views/dynaForm.jsf) (version 0.7.1) i always get null as values returned from dynamic form.

My xhtml:

```
<h:form id="messageParamsForm" styleClass="formBlock dynaForm">
            <pe:dynaForm id="dynaForm" value="#{editParametersBean.formModel}" var="data">
                <pe:dynaFormControl type="textfield" for="textfield">
                    <p:inputText id="txt" value="#{data.value}" />
                </pe:dynaFormControl>

                <pe:dynaFormControl type="grouplabel" for="grouplabel">

                </pe:dynaFormControl>

                <pe:dynaFormControl type="separator" for="separator">
                    <p:separator />
                </pe:dynaFormControl>

                <pe:dynaFormControl type="checkbox" for="checkbox">
                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkbox" value="#{data.value}"/>
                </pe:dynaFormControl>
            </pe:dynaForm>
<div class="buttonsBlock">
                <p:commandButton value="#{msg['button.apply']}"
                                 update="@form"
                                 action="#{editParametersBean.save()}"
                                 styleClass="primaryButton"/>
        </div>
        </h:form>
```

This is how i create form model

```
formModel = new DynaFormModel();
        for (MessageParamValueDto parameterValue : messageParameterValues) {
            DynaFormRow row = formModel.createRegularRow();
            DynaFormLabel label = row.addLabel(parameterValue.getParameter().getLabel(), 1, 1);
            DynaFormControl control = row.addControl(parameterValue, parameterValue.getParameter().getType(), 1, 1);
            label.setForControl(control);
        }
```

Bean is view scoped.

And this is the DTO

```
public class MessageParamValueDto {

    private MessageParameter parameter;
    private Object value;

    public MessageParamValueDto(MessageParameter parameter, Object value) {
        this.parameter = parameter;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public MessageParamValueDto() {
        // NO CODE
    }

    public MessageParameter getParameter() {
        return parameter;
    }

    public void setParameter(MessageParameter parameter) {
        this.parameter = parameter;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

When i process form in save method all dtos have null values.
I also sometimes get `Component ID ... has already been found in the view.` But it is completely nondeterministic.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think you process the form? Value of the process attribute is @this per default. You should point process to the pe:dynaForm. Try process=":messageParamsForm:dynaForm" or process="dynaForm".